# How to extract all the integers from a string and convert it to a specified char value in Java?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, numberformatexception

The problem statement is to find the numbers between a String and find the appropriate character for the given number. To be specific, 0 represents 'a', 1 represents 'b', 2 represents 'c'... like so on. And then again 26 represents 'a', 27- 'b', 28- 'c'....goes on like this.

For better understanding:

```
Input String: ab1ab

Output: b
```

Explanation: there is one integer value '1' in the string which represents 'b'.

```
Input String 2: abcd00hdjhs1224

Output: ac
```

Explanation: there are two integer values '00' and '1224' which represent 'a' and 'c' respectively.

The problem with my solution was that when I was storing the integer values into int or long data type, large values threw NumberFormatException.

What would be a better approach to overcome this problem? More than a programming problem it's algorithmic problem. How can I achieve the solution without worrying about the large number or the BigInteger class?

Note: If multiple integers occur then the whole is considered as one integer value.(That is where the problem occurs for me)

Comment: Did you forget to paste your solution?

Comment: You can't. You need to treat that value as a number. So either use `long` or `BigInteger`.

Comment: It kinda depends on how "large" the numbers can be. Both int and long have limitations and you will have to use BigInteger instead at some point.

Comment: When you are reading each new digit d of the number, to form the number you would do number *= 10 and then number += d. But since you only care about the remainder modulo 26, then you can compute the remainder after each update number = number%26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulus operation is distributive over addition and multiplication. i.e.

- (A+B)%n = (A%n + B%n) %n
- (A*B)%n = (A%n * B%n) %n

What is it good for?

Assume "abcdefgh" represents a large number where a-h are the digits of that number. It is obvious that :

- abcdefgh = (abcde * 1000 + fgh) or
- abcdefgh = (a * 10000000 + bcdefgh) or
- abcdefgh = (a*10000000 + b*1000000 + c*100000 + d*10000 + e*1000 + f*100 + g*10 + h)

As you are only interested in the reaults of `yourDigits%26` you can scan every number found in your input string from left to right and multiply by 10 and add the next number and take the modulo and store this as new answer until you reach the end of the string:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println(mapNumbersToCharsAndConcat("ab1ab"));
    System.out.println(mapNumbersToCharsAndConcat("abcd00hdjhs1224"));
}
static String mapNumbersToCharsAndConcat (String input){
    char[] myChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();       
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while(m.find()){
        String num = m.group();
        sb.append(myChars[modFromString(num)]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
static int modFromString(String num){
    int res = 0;   
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++){
        res = (res * 10 + (int)num.charAt(i) - '0') % 26; 
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: If multiple integers occur then the whole is considered as one integer >value.(That is where the problem occurs for me)

This is not the problem you don't have to keep the whole integer.

Suppose I give you 1872368486184712442 and ask you to divide by 26 what will you do ?

Yes exactly this is the key point to solve this problem.

here is the simple snippet of code

```
String ans="",s1="1abb00hjsdj";
for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
  if(s1.charAt(i)>='0' && s1.charAt(i)<='9'){
    int num=0;
    while(i<s1.length() && s1.charAt(i)>='0' && s1.charAt(i)<='9'){
      num=(num*10+s1.charAt(i)-'0')%26;
      i++;
    }
    ans=ans+Character.toString((char)('a'+num));
  } else {
    continue;
  }
}
System.out.println(ans);
```

Comment: That is the point! How can I perform modulus(%) without storing the actual value or without specifying the type? That is the part I'm stuck with. I don't know if there's a conceptual problem or programming logic problem.

Comment: for all continuous integers start with num=0 then for subsequent integers do              (num*10+nextnum)%26 keep doing that upto end, the num in the end is your character in alphabets

Comment: sure i have added simple java implementation

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to care about digits only, reading digits, parsing them, and then repeat.

It's O(N) time complexity.

Your algorithm would be like:

```
String chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String str = "abcd00hdjhs1224";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
int index = 0;
while (index < str.length()) {
     StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
     int charIndex = -1;
     while (index < str.length() && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(index))) {
            number.append(str.charAt(index));
            index++;
        }

        if (!number.toString().isEmpty()){
            charIndex = Integer.parseInt(number.toString()) % 26;
        }

     if (charIndex != -1){
         result.append(chars.charAt(charIndex));
     }
     index++;
}
```

You didn't mention the constraint of digits nor the constraint of your string length.

Comment: You will get a NumberFormatException for the input "abc999999999999def" when you try to parse 999999999999 with `Integer.parseInt`